# Oracle 10g - Determine the date a Trigger was last updated

Tags: oracle, date, triggers, oracle10g

Is there a way you can determine the date when a trigger was updated?
The reason why I ask is because a costumer complained about receiving some erros in our application, but when I went to look at the table, it had all triggers disabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select object_name, object_type, created, timestamp
from user_objects
where object_name = 'nameOfYourTrigger'
```

The timestamp column will show the last touch.

Comment: This may or may not be the last time someone made a *material* change to the trigger -- altering the table can invalidate that trigger, and Oracle will implicitly recompile that trigger on the table, which will update that timestamp.

Comment: @Adam - good point - the timestamp on the table should be evaluated in the context of this.  Of course, the table timestamp will additionally change when grants are made on the table - one of my pet peeves.

Comment: You could look at adding a trigger on DDL changes, recording various details from v$session (program, machine, etc). But I would presume only a very restricted number of people have the DBA access required to disable the triggers anyway.